# Reinstall /Library/Python on OS X Leopard

Tags: python, macos, osx-leopard, reinstall

I accidentally removed /Library/Python on OS X Leopard. How can I reinstall that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Library/Python` contains your python site-packages, which is the local software you've installed using commands like `python setup.py install`. The pieces here are third-party packages, not items installed by Apple - your actual Python installation is still safe in /System/Library/etc...

In other words, the default OS leaves these directories mostly blank... nothing in there is critical (just a readme and a path file).

In this case, you'll have to :

1. Recreate the directory structure:
2. Re-install your third-party libraries.

The directory structure on a default OS X install is:

> /Library/Python/2.3/site-packages
>   /Library/Python/2.5/site-packages

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like, I'll create a tarball from a pristine installation.  I'm using MacOSX 10.5.7, and only 12K.

Comment: On its way to the address you list on your CV at pittle.org.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using 10.4, but unless the installation changed dramatically in 10.5, `/Library/Python` is just a place to install local (user-installed) packages; the actual Python install is under `/System`. On 10.4, I have the following structure:

```
/Library/
    Python/
        2.3/
            README
            site-packages/
                README
```

So just re-creating that structure may suffice. (But instead of `2.3`, use the version of Python installed on 10.5.)