# how to recover python 2.6.1 that was pre-installed in my macbook pro?

Tags: python

I download python 3.2 and my first thought was that I need to uninstall the python 2.6.1 pre-installed in my computer. But later I found in python.org **"You should never modify or delete these, as they are Apple-controlled and are used by Apple- or third-party software"**. I used **"sudo rm -rf /Library/Frameworks/Python.Framework"** to delete python 2.6.1. Now I truly want to undo this command(I want python 2.6.1 back!). What should I do?
(or the question can be expressed as follows: how can I re-install the pre-installed python 2.6.1 in my mac?)

Comment: This should probably be posted on superuser.com instead, as SO deals mainly with helping with programming issues. Here is a link to a question on how to reinstall it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/917876/reinstall-library-python-on-os-x-leopard

Comment: As for 'upgrading' Python on mac, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1541776/upgrade-python-to-2-6-on-mac

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry, that command will not remove it. The Apple-supplied Python in Mac OS X 10.6 is located at `/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/python2.6
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  75 Nov  7 23:52 /usr/bin/python2.6@ -> ../../System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/bin/python2.6
```

Anything in `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework` was not put there by Apple, rather most likely by a python.org Python installer.  The way to be sure is type:

```
$ /usr/bin/python2.6
Python 2.6.1 (r261:67515, Jun 24 2010, 21:47:49) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

That's the signature of the current Apple-supplied Python 2.6 in Mac OS X 10.6.

In general, do not modify or delete files in `/System/Library` or in `/usr` other than `/usr/local`.  Files in `/Library` are under your control.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling would work. In the future, don't delete Frameworks you didn't install.